# ANDROID - How to clear animation-list applied to ImageView

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have an animation-list stored in res/anim/draw_circle_violet.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list android:oneshot="true"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:duration="10" android:drawable="@drawable/plainimg"/>
    <item android:duration="10" android:drawable="@drawable/circlev1"/>
    <item android:duration="10" android:drawable="@drawable/circlev2"/>
    <item android:duration="10" android:drawable="@drawable/circlev3"/>
    <item android:duration="10" android:drawable="@drawable/circlev4"/>
    <item android:duration="10" android:drawable="@drawable/circlev5"/>
    <item android:duration="10" android:drawable="@drawable/circlev6"/>
    <item android:duration="10" android:drawable="@drawable/circlev7"/>
    <item android:duration="10" android:drawable="@drawable/circlev8"/>
</animation-list>
```

This animation is applied to an ImageView :

```
mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.draw_circle_violet);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mImageView
                .getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();
```

I click a button to clear animation applied to this ImageView :

```
     mImageView.clearAnimation();
```

but animation can't be removed. ANother way, I try this :

```
     mImageView.setAnimation(null);
```

but not successfull.

Plz help.

---

Update : I have tried

```
    frameAnimation.stop();
```

but animation still applied to ImageView. Any ideal ?
Here is my [source code](http://www.mediafire.com/download/1yc1dg84aez2vxd/ClearAnimation.zip)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
frameAnimation.stop();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have tried this but animation still applied to ImageView. Any ideal ? Thank for reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty way, but works:

`setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Let me know if this didn't solve your issue.

Comment: There is no method such as setBackground() applied to ImageView. There are only 3 methods : setBackgroundColor(int color), setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background),setBackgroundResource(int resid), that applied to ImageView. Plz check. Thank for your reply.

Comment: My bad `setBackground` method is for API 16. You can use `setBackgroundDrawable`